# How to have functions chaining in R like in c# with linq we have method chaining?

Tags: r

I am a  new-bee to R one thing I noticed in R that we need to keep on saving the result to the variable each time before further processing is required. Is there some way where I can store the result to some buffer and later on use this buffer result in further processing.
For people who are familiar with c# using LINQ we have a feature called Method Chaining, here we keep on passing the intermediate result to various functions on the fly without the need of storing them into separate variables and in the end, we get the required output.This saves lots of extra syntax, so is there something like this in R?

Comment: Yeah... just pass the results along.  You aren't required to save the results like `tmp <- rnorm(100); hist(tmp)` you could just `hist(rnorm(100))`.

Answer (score 4):

Function composition is to functional programming as method chaining is to object-oriented programming.

```
x <- foo(bar(baz(y)))
```

is basically the same as

```
x = baz(y).bar().foo()
```

in the languages you might be familiar with.

If you're uncomfortable with nested parens and writing things backwards, the magrittr package provides the `%>%` operator to unpack expressions:

```
library(magrittr)
x = y %>% baz() %>% bar() %>% foo()
```

R also provides a couple of frameworks for conventional OO programming: reference classes and R6. With those, you can write something like

```
x = y$baz()$bar()$foo()
```

but I'd suggest learning how to deal with "normal" R expressions first.

Comment: I was going to revoke the upvote for a second but your edit fixed my complaint.

Comment: Say what you will about pipes, they fix this backwards-writing thing very nicely

Comment: R sure seems to like verbose (ugly) operators. Seems like `||` was available for piping (if non-directional) not to mention `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

In R we have something called **Pipes(%>%)** through which one can send the output of one function to another, i.e output from one function becomes input for subsequent function in the chain.
Try something like in this in R console Consider a **tibble MyData** containing Username and pwd as two columns u can use pipes as:

MyData %>%
select(username,pwd)
%>%
filter(!is.na(username))%>%
arrange(username).

This will print all the usernames and pwd sorted by username that contains non NA's value
Hope that helps

Comment: yeah pipes that is what i was looking for